# Calculate percentage of values in an array with a certain condition

Tags: array, vb.net

I had to write a function that calculates the percentage of values in table less or equal to 2.  Is my code right or is there anything missing?

```
Public Function intPercentage As Integer

 Dim intAge( , ) As Integer = {{0, 2, 5, 10}

 {2, 0, 1, 3}

 {5, 1, 0, 6}

 {10, 3, 6, 0}}

Dim intRow, intCol As Integer

For intRow= 0 to 3

 For intCol = 0 to 3

 If intAge(intRow, intCol) >= 2 Then

 intTotal = intTotal + intAge(intRow, intCol)

 Next intCol

   Next intRow

 intPercentage = intTotal / 100

 End Function
```

Comment: Does it work for all test cases you can imagine? What test cases did you imagine?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel the calculation? yes the calculation works fine afaik, i'm more interested in finding out of anyone could pick out anything wrong with my code, just a second opinion

Comment: This question confuses me. The description says *"calculates the percentage of values in table less or equal to 2"* but the code says: `If intAge(intRow, intCol) >= 2 Then intTotal = intTotal + intAge(intRow, intCol)`. Two things, 1. are you looking for ages less than 2, or greater, and 2. are you averaging their ages, or getting the % of ages above/belop the 2 threshold?

Answer (score 3):

## Naming

**Kill the [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). Kill it with fire. Don't bother taking it out back to bury it.**

[image: kill it with fire]

[Hungarian notation can be done right](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html), but using it to tell yourself what datatype a variable is is ***not*** doing it right. Even if you must just *insist* on using hungarian notation this would not be right.

> ```
> Dim intAge( , ) As Integer = {{0, 2, 5, 10}
> ```

`intAge` is not an integer. It is an ***array*** of arrays of integers.

Functions/Subs should have Verb-Noun style names. They should also be `PascalCased`.

## Indentation

It's important. Like, *really really* important. Proper indentation makes it orders of magnitude easier to read code. Considering code will be read *many* more times than it will be written, it's important to make sure people can read it.

Everything inside of `Function...End Function` should be indented one level. Everything inside of `For...Next` should be indented one more level. Same goes for `If...End If` blocks.

## Getting Down to Business

- A percentage is a double, not an integer.

  > ```
  > Public Function intPercentage As Integer
  > ```

  If you *want* an integer representation of the percentage, you should probably leave a comment explaining why.
- A function isn't much good if it will return the same results every time. This one will because you've hardcoded the array of arrays into the function. It would be much more useful to accept a 2-dimensional array as an argument instead.
- I'm not personally a fan of declaring multiple variables on a single line, but there's technically nothing wrong with it.

  > ```
  > Dim intRow, intCol As Integer
  > ```
- Since we're now going to accept an array as an argument, we'll no longer be able to hardcode `For row = 0 to 3`. You'll need to call [GetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) on the internal array and [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx) on the outer one. (Example will be below.)
- You never declared `intTotal`. (Which you're going to call `totalAge` now, right?)
- Don't skimp on the `End If`s. Always be sure to close the `If` block unless you really write a one liner. (I don't recommend one liners by the way.)
- Prefer the [Return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s.aspx) keyword over assigning values to the function name.
- You can't just divide a number by 100 and call it a percentage.

  > ```
  > intPercentage = intTotal / 100
  > ```

  In order to get the results you're really after, you need to divide the count of ages 2 or older by the count of all ages, then multiply by 100.

I took the liberty of re-writing the code.

```
Public Function GetPercentage(ages(,) As Integer) As Double

    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim overTwo As Integer
    Dim total As Integer

    For row = 0 to ages.Length - 1
        total = total + ages.GetLength(row)

        For col = 0 to ages.GetLength(row) - 1
            If ages(row, col) >= 2 Then
                overTwo = overTwo + 1
            End If
        Next col
    Next row

    Return (overTwo / total) * 100
End Function
```

Comment: You're welcome. Out of curiousity, what exactly are you trying to return from this function?

Comment: I had to get the percentage of values in table less or equal to 2

Comment: @shaka compared to the total number of entries in the table, correct?

Comment: Yeah basically that

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.